# ffmpeg two-pass in ts stream production

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

How can I make a two-pass convert while using .ts chunks output?

I use the following command inside bash script for chunks generation (I think all variables are clear enough for understanding):

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -threads 1 -b:v ${selected_bitrate} -b:a ${audio_bitrate} -s ${selected_width}x${selected_height} -r ${framerate} -preset fast -level ${level} -vcodec libx264 -f ssegment -segment_list b${selected_bitrate}.m3u8 -segment_time 9 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*9)" -y b${selected_bitrate}_%05d.ts
```

I want to try two-pass because I need to match desired bitrate more accurate. Right now when I use for example 200k bitrate for video stream, it results ~380k in ts chunks (of course without audio).

Answer (score 2):

Just call the libx264 with "-pass 1" like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -threads 1 -ar -b:v ${selected_bitrate} -s ${selected_width}x${selected_height} -r ${framerate} -preset fast -level ${level} -vcodec libx264 -pass 1 -f null -
```

Then repeat your command with "-pass 2":

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -threads 1 -b:v ${selected_bitrate} -b:a ${audio_bitrate} -s    ${selected_width}x${selected_height} -r ${framerate} -preset fast -level ${level} -vcodec libx264 -pass 2 -f ssegment -segment_list b${selected_bitrate}.m3u8 -segment_time 9 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*9)" -y b${selected_bitrate}_%05d.ts
```

That should give you what you want.